# Using scoped `polymorphic_allocator` with `boost::circular_buffer` fails

Tags: c++, c++17, c++pmr, boost-circularbuffer

**Background**

I want to use `boost::circular_buffer` with a scoped C++17 `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`. I.e. I want the same allocator for an outer container to be used for inner containers.

*Side note*:

`boost::circular_buffer` [is allocator-aware](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/template_params.html) and the following assertion is true:

```cpp
static_assert(std::uses_allocator_v<
                boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>>,
                std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>>);
```

In this scenario I have a vector of circular buffers. With default allocator it would be of type `std::vector<boost::circular_buffer<T>>`

Using `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` I express it as:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>

template<class T>
using Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>;
using Inner = boost::circular_buffer<int, Alloc<int>>;
using Outer = std::pmr::vector<Inner>;
```

Using these aliases, `Inner` works with `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`, but not as element of `Outer`.

The following works:

```cpp
Outer::allocator_type alloc1; // Allocator type used by Outer to allocate Inner
Inner::allocator_type alloc2; // Allocator type used by Inner to allocate ints
// circular_buffer works if used directly with polymorphic_allocator
Inner inner1; // default arg OK
Inner inner2(alloc1); // pmr with allocator as last argument, also implicitly converts OK
Inner inner3(1, alloc2); // pmr with allocator as last argument OK

// Use to instantiate member functions
inner1.set_capacity(16);
inner2.set_capacity(16);
inner3.set_capacity(16);
inner1.push_back(1);
inner2.push_back(1);
inner3.push_back(1);
```

But when used as scoped allocator (which `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` supports [without any need for `std::scoped_allocator_adapter`](https://youtu.be/RLezJuqNcEQ?t=1334)) it fails to compile with [difficult to interpret errors](https://godbolt.org/z/4n1Gjhqxh).

One of the errors is a `static_assertion` failure because `circular_buffer` is not constructible using the provided allocator, which I'm reproducing (possibly incorrectly) but without triggering assertion here:

```cpp
Outer v;
/* Statically asserts because Inner is not constructible

c++/12.0.0/bits/uses_allocator.h:98:60:error: static assertion failed: construction with an allocator must be possible if uses_allocator is true
98 |           is_constructible<_Tp, _Args..., const _Alloc&>>::value,

[with
_Args = {};
_Tp = boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> >;
_Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> > >;
std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> >&]
*/

// Note: Adding prefix `A` to make names allowed
using A_Tp = boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> >;
using A_Alloc = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> > >;
static_assert(std::is_constructible<Inner, const A_Alloc&>::value); // OK
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Inner, A_Tp>); // OK
static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Outer::allocator_type, A_Alloc>); // OK
v.emplace_back(); // ERROR
v.emplace_back(1); // ERROR
```

**Compiler explorer link**

https://godbolt.org/z/4n1Gjhqxh

**Questions**

1. Am I using `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` incorrectly here?
2. What is the compiler trying to tell me with the error?
3. Why is the reproduced assertion not failing as it is when used from `emplace_back`?
4. Does `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` introduce any new/additional allocator requirements that make it incompatible with `boost::circular_buffer` or is this an issue with `boost::circular_buffer`?

**Edit**

- Added prefix `A` in replication of STL template parameters.

Comment: Well, `_Alloc` makes your program ill formed, no diagnostic required.  Fixing that won't fix your problem.  (Stop mimicing std header files, it uses mangled names because those mangled names are reserved for its use).  No `_` followed by a capital letter in your code ever, or `__`.

Comment: I kept same names to make it obvious what I was trying to show as it didn't make any difference on the result. I nevertheless corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scoped allocator protocol requires that *every constructor* of the type has a corresponding allocator-extended version (either by appending an allocator parameter to the parameter list, or by prepending two parameters - `allocator_arg_t` followed by the allocator).

That includes the copy and move constructors, for which `boost::circular_buffer` doesn't appear to provide allocator-extended versions. The requirement for these two allocator-extended constructors in particular is in the C++11 allocator-aware container requirements.

For `vector` in particular, `emplace_back` needs to be able to copy or move existing elements on a reallocation, which is why it needs the allocator-extended copy/move constructor.

Comment: To paraphrase for my own understanding: "There must be a valid constructor overload that accepts an allocator according to 'Uses-allocator construction'". The `emplace_back` requirement that is not fulfilled seems to be [_MoveInsertable_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable).

Answer (score 0):

The first error message states that this isn't valid:

```
std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> > > alice;

boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> > bob(
  std::declval<boost::circular_buffer<int, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int> >>(),
  alice
);
```

it appears to be trying to copy the circular buffer while passing in an allocator as the 2nd argument.

No overload of `circular_buffer` accepts these two arguments.

```
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v< Inner, Inner, Alloc<int>& >);
```

that is basically the assertion that is failing.

Comment: Isn't that the second error? The first error from `emplace_back` has `with _Args = {}` so does not attempt to perform any copy construction from what I can tell.
Can subsequent errors be trusted to not be misleading given this? In particular since it seems to perform the ["Uses-allocator construction"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator#Uses-allocator_construction)?

Comment: I used the 4n1 godbolt, and decoded the first error message I saw.  That error message appears to you can't construct itnusing a different allocator (a pmr to a buffer, as opposed to a pmr to an int).